# How about a polling question?

Tags: discussion, polling

Alright, we all know polls are [bad, evil, no good, rotten garbage and they have no place on the Stack Exchange network](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And yet...

...it seems to be working pretty darn well over at [TeX Meta](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1564). Brief summary for the click-through impaired: a single CW question, where the polls are answers and the responses are comments.

The way I see it, this could be a good thing. No, it wouldn't stop people from asking "What is the best {thing}" questions on Stack Overflow, but it would provide an outlet for those questions and might at least be marginally interesting. Additionally, it would mean that when people inevitably come here to ask "Why was my question closed, where can I ask it?" we could say something other than "Somewhere else, now go away."

So what do you guy and gals think? Is this something that might work on MSO, or are polls still verboten?

Comment: So what is the value of that poll?  I'm not seeing how it's making the site better.  The raw stats of how many people like this or that option doesn't seem particularly useful information.

Comment: ...especially when it would rely on only the portion of the community that happened to see it, and the portion of those that decided to answer. You can conduct polls all over the place, facebook, SurveyMonkey, etc. Why not use one of those venues instead of trying to change Stack Overflow? If you wanted to promote to this audience, you could always buy banner ads...

Comment: FWIW, WebApps tried this too at one point. It didn't really work all that well for them.

Comment: Our definitions of "pretty darn well" must differ significantly. That whole thing looks terrible.

Comment: @Bart and how, I agree 100%

Comment: Anyway, what I kinda liked about the Tex poll is that it allowed for people to learn about new tools/resources. For example, the first answer (favorite editor): if there's a useful/alternative editor that I've never heard of but got a lot of votes, I'd definitely check it out and it might change everything. Just an example.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Looking at that question, I kinda hear a site like http://slant.co snicker and think "Ah look, how cute. They awkwardly try what we're doing well".

Comment: I feel a strange sense of pride in that this my most downvoted post across the network. I feel like I've somehow achieved something.

Comment: There are vastly better formats for polls, like multiple choice boxes that auto-collate the data for example; they would be much better for polling than a stack exchange question

Comment: @Rich yes, that is true. I mainly brought this up as an outlet for the large number of people who insist on asking polling questions here.

Comment: The duplicate says "do not belong on the serious **main** SE sites". Is the proposal here Main or Meta? ..... Oh, is there such a thing as non-serious main site?

Comment: @braso meta. A single post on MSO.

Comment: @Bart here's the difference: I've never heard of slant.co. I (obviously) have heard of stack overflow.

Comment: Just because I don't know about the car mechanic having a shop around the corner, doesn't mean I should ask my butcher for advice.

Comment: Mike, IMO, this should focus on All Metas. **It is** something that TeX folks *have already done*, **with Moderation support**. Is this an acceptable format on other Metas? Here, MSO, it obviously have been already shot down...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > I think this question is...

Comment: ... Oscillating

Comment: @Bart this answer is supposed to act as a poll. So upvote the comments that you agree with.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Way to abuse the poll by just posting actual comments in the comment section.  (FYI, the irony here is intentional)

Comment: ...likely to solicit unclear debate or spam and should be CW'd to superuser due to a lack of expert experience and too many possible good answers within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: This is not constructive...

Comment: ...at all, anyhow

Answer (score 8):

Why do we need this? SE is the wrong place for polls, and the fact that someone made it work doesn't make it right.

Even if it might "work" that doesn't make it a good thing. Polls are opinion based, have no right answer, and mostly serve as a distraction. I'm surprised that TeX's mods haven't removed that thread already.

As @Servy said, it doesn't improve the site, and it doesn't give anyone a concrete answer.

Comment: If you look at the question history it was actually suggested by one off their mods and discussed before it was implemented. http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/1564/1

Comment: There were many questions which were polls and I (and the lot of people who voted them up) found them useful. I don't see the problem **at all** with intentional polls.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's an extreme clever hack for using the software for another purpose of what it was intended. And as I'm reading it, this would be a **Meta Tool** for some inner statistics that the community wants to make. It is not like we're opening the gates of Shopping Questions on the main sites.

If the specific community agrees it's a valid tool, then why not? Or are the the TeX people doing something *illegal* for Stack Exchange standards?

PS: seeing the first manifestation of disagreement, I'd like to reinforce that my premises are:

- it is clever
- it is valid (as a Meta tool)